# Max value in a named tupple

Tags: python, tuples

am new to programming..Am trying to find the max value in a named tuple. I have the following code:

```
Book = namedtuple('Book', 'author title genre year price instock')

BSI = [
Book('George Orwell', 'Animal Farm', 'Fiction', 1945, 9.99, 21),
Book('J.K. Rowling', 'Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince', 'Fantasy', 2007, 24.26, 32)]
```

I made the following code to find the inventory value (last two element (price*instock))

```
def inventory_value(b: Book)->str:
return (b.price * b.instock)
```

However when I tried to find the maximum value using the following code..it doesn't seem to work.

```
def top_value (b: Book):
for item in b:
    return(max(inventory_value(item)))
```

Trying  to find the max. inventory value.

If I just use print statement in the top_value function..it gives the right values.
     print(inventory_value(item))

```
 209.79
 776.32
```

How can I find the max value in this case?

Comment: As an off-topic aside, function annotations still mess me up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `max` with `key`:

```
>>> def inventory_value(b: Book)->str:
...     return (b.price * b.instock)
... 
>>> max(BSI, key=inventory_value)
Book(author='J.K. Rowling', title='Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince', genre='Fantasy', year=2007, price=24.26, instock=32)
```

Comment: Thanks Ashwini...What if I only wanted the value and not the whole thing?

Comment: @user3233949 Then use `max` with a generator expression: `max(inventory_value(t) for t in BSI)`

Comment: Or `inventory_value(max(BSI, key=inventory_value))`

Answer (score 0):

You can add inventory_value as a property to the named tuple, then you dont need a seperate function to find a books inventory_value, then use max with key=operator.attrgetter('inventory_value')

```
from collections import namedtuple
import operator


class Book(namedtuple('Book', 'author title genre year price instock')):
    __slots__ = ()

    @property
    def inventory_value(self):
        return self.price * self.instock

BSI = [
Book('George Orwell', 'Animal Farm', 'Fiction', 1945, 9.99, 21),
Book('J.K. Rowling', 'Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince',
     'Fantasy', 2007, 24.26, 32)]

print max(BSI, key=operator.attrgetter('inventory_value'))
```